# Help calculating $\sum^{R}_{k=1} \bigl\lfloor{\sqrt { R^2-k^2}}\bigr\rfloor$

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

I'm trying to calculate, or at least approximate,
$$\sum^{R}_{k=1} \left\lfloor{\sqrt { R^2-k^2}}\right\rfloor,$$
where $R$ is a natural number.

I have tried factoring this as
$$\sum_{k=1}^R \left\lfloor \sqrt {(R+k)(R-k)} \right\rfloor,$$
but then I don't know where to go from there.

Comment: Please confirm that this question is typed correctly, including the floor function.

Comment: sorry there are changes.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Have you separated the function like $\sum^{R}_{k=1} \lfloor{\sqrt {(R-k)(R+k)}}\rfloor$?

Comment: @abiessu Yes , but have done that but then I have no hint and this makes things more complicated.

Comment: For a crude approximation, we can use an integral.

Comment: @AndréNicolas can you please elaborate about the integral?

Comment: The question has been answered. This is a classical problem, with a huge literature on the error term. Integration is a first step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $\sqrt{R^2-k^2}$ is a decreasing function of $k$, we have 
$$\frac{\pi}{4}R^2=\int_0^R\sqrt{R^2-k^2}dk > \sum_{k=1}^R \sqrt{R^2-k^2}  > \int_1^{R}\sqrt{R^2-k^2}dk>\frac{\pi}{4}R^2-R$$

Answer (score 2):

This is known as [Gauss's circle problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssCircleProblem.html), and is essentially the same as counting the number of points with integer coordinates inside a circle.

There doesn't appear to be any known way of calculating this sum faster than by summing the terms one by one.